# How to get missing data using Django model query?

Tags: python, django

In Django, there is the `filter()` method to filter data. So I can pass an array of data and get the filtered results like this `model.objects.filter(id__in=id_array)`.

Is there a way to get missing data using Django model query? 
How to get a list of `id_array` elements which don't exist in the database?

Comment: there's no such information in the db, so the db cannot return you missing ids.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't ask the database for things it doesn't have. However, you can ask it for all the things it does have, and then get a set containing the difference. Something like:

```
ids = model.objects.filter(id__in=id_array).distinct().values_list('id', flat=True)
missing_values = set(id_array) - ids
```

Comment: Why not use `exclude` as such: `ids = model.objects.exclude(id__in=id_array).distinct().values_list('id', flat=True)`

Comment: Actually the above would just give the entries in the database that are not in `id_array`. OP wanted entries in `id_array` that are not in database. Never mind.